# Is it possible to do ImportRange in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been playing around with Google Apps Script today and I am trying to code some custom spreadsheet functions.  I have done some searching but cannot find an answer to my query.

I know that on a Google Spreadsheet you can use ImportRange in a cell on a spreadsheet like this:

```
=ImportRange(spreadsheet_key;sheet!range_of_cells)
```

My questions are is it possible to do something similar in a Google Apps Script and if so, how?

I want to import a range of cells from a sheet on another spreadsheet (not a sheet on the spreadsheet where the script will reside).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly possible. You just need to call `SpreadsheetApp.openById` and then get the desired sheet and ranges normally.

Please take a look at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_range) : `range.getValues()` and `range.setValues()` are very basic GAS methods and are pretty well described.

Read [the tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_common_tasks) as well.

Comment: I'm aware of these functions but I don't see how I can tell it to pick the range from **another** spreadsheet.  Maybe I'm just being stupid again.

Comment: Hi Serge, I took the liberty to edit your answer to address his doubt on the comment :)

Comment: @Henrique : thanks for the 'edit', you're perfectly right, I still have some progress to do on some answers formatting and 'completeness'  I'll take care of that ;-)

Comment: Thanks Serge and Henrique, I see how to do it now.  Great help once again.

Comment: What's GAS supposed to mean?

Comment: Google Apps Script

Answer (score 3):

It seems Google, in their infinite wisdom, has altered the behavior of openById and similar functions. They are no longer allowed in the context of custom functions.

See https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5174 for more details.

They suggest using IMPORTRANGE as a workaround, but as previously mentioned, this needs to be called within a cell.

Our solution was to use IMPORTRANGE in the sheet, and pass the acquired data into our custom function, as the data set was small. I hope this information helps!

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do this recently. This is what I came up with, simply hard-coding the spreadsheet key and range into ahab's `myImportRange` function

```
// to be used in the spreadsheet like so:  = myScriptedImportRange( GoogleClock() )
// no need to include key or range because they are in the script here
// 
// the third parameter - GoogleClock() - triggers an automatic update every minute.
// updated 2011-07-17 (ahab): better regex to strip sheetname of *outer* single quotes
// updated 2013-01-27 (ben) to hard-code key and range 
function myScriptedImportRange(  ) { 
 var key = "PUT YOUR DATA_SPREADSHEET_ID IN HERE"
 var sheetrange = "PUT YOUR SHEET AND CELL RANGE IN HERE"
 var shra = sheetrange.split("!") ;
 if (shra.length==1) shra[1]=shra[0], shra[0]="";  

 var sheetstring = shra[0].replace( /^'(.*)'$/g , "$1") // was: replace( /'/g , "") ; updated 2011-07-17 (ahab)
 var rangestring = shra[1] 

 var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById( key )    
 if ( sheetstring.length==0 ) sheet = source.getSheets()[0] ;
 else sheet = source.getSheetByName( sheetstring ) ;

 return  sheet.getRange( rangestring ).getValues(); 
}
```

In my case I have a set of private sheets, an intermediate sheet that uses the regular `myImportRange` and VMERGE with some SQL to combine selections from the private sheets into the intermediate sheet, and then a public sheet that simply has one cell containing `= myScriptedImportRange( GoogleClock() )`

Note that there is a similar approach here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11857014

Note also that the `ImportRange` function and related functions often have a problem of not displaying the imported data when the origin workbook(s) is/are not open. A simple way around this has been described in a comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11786797

Comment: The Google clock function no longer works in the New Google Sheets and it does not let you put the alternative function "NOW()" into the main function within the sheet. It just keeps saying loading and nothing happens.