# Triggered functions and IMPORTRANGE

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, importrange

I have a Google Apps Script that compares information submitted in a Google form to information that is brought into the Google spreadsheet using the IMPORTRANGE function.  The script works perfectly if I run it manually but if it runs from the form submit trigger it reports that it isn't getting the correct information from the cells using IMPORTRANGE.

Is there a way around this, like is there a quick function I can add that forces import range to update?

I have already tried to add a wait time of up to 10 minutes and it hasn't changed the results.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is with how functions like `importRange` works. Actually, they require the same access/permissions as the user account logged in using them, to avoid security holes (imagine an editor of a spreadsheet you own accessing other spreadsheets you have not shared with them).

Because of this (well, at least that's what I think), these formulas are only evaluated when you have the spreadsheet opened. When you close it and leave the script to run on a trigger, it will not find any result on the expected cells.

An easy workaround for this is to fetch the data using the script itself and quit using `importRange`. It's very easy to do, e.g.

```js
var values = SpreadsheetApp.openById('external-spreadsheet-key').
  getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('A1:D100').getValues();
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('DestSheet').
  getRange(1,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values);
```

Obviously that the spreadsheet key, sheet's names and ranges are just an example here.

Comment: Just a tip, since you're new to StackOverflow, you should mark an answer as accepted when you feel you got a good one. Voting (up and down) is also another nice feature we have here. This is not a mailing list ;)