# Function IMPORTRANGE is not updating

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, importrange

I want to use the IMPORTRANGE function every time I open one spreadsheet so this opened spreadsheet can be synchronized with another spreadsheet. So, in A1, I put a call formula like this:

```
=importrange("0AmEr9uNtZwnNdDFKMTVlbmZYZ3ZyOWM0aXpZS2twM1x";  "myData!A1:W384")
```

But this IMPORTRANGE call remains static. That is, once imported, the data isn't updated when the imported sheet is changed.

So what is wrong? I wonder if I can use IMPORTRANGE, a spreadsheet function, within a Google Apps Script (which is like JS code).

How can I call a spreadsheet function inside a script?

Comment: I think there is a answer to a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143684/is-it-possible-to-do-importrange-in-google-apps-script . So, there's no way to use specifically the `importrange()`. I have to use `range.getValues()` and `range.setValues()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ImportRange` does update automatically—just not instantly. Give it 5 minutes.

1. It won't update until you open the spreadsheet and
2. The one opening it must have "read" permission to the source.

If you really want to do it with code, use `SpreadsheetApp.openById`, `getSheetByName`, and `getRange` `get`/`setValues`.

Comment: One problem I see with `importrange()` is that it doesn't import comments. Are there a way to solve this?

Comment: no, cant be done from importRange which imports only data. Even with gas you cant get comments, only cell notes which are different (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getNotes())