# Can't use getValues() with IMPORTRANGE

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I have a Spreadsheet where I have used `IMPORTRANGE` to pull data from another spreadsheet. I also have a script that always gets the last row of specific columns, fills a form, create a link and send it to someone.

I'm trying to use `getValues()` to get the value of a specific cell that has been filled with data from `IMPORTRANGE` function.

```
function askForPrice() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xXx');
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

var range1 = ss.getRange('A1').getDataRegion().getLastRow();
var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();

var formUrl = ss.getFormUrl();     
var form = FormApp.openByUrl('xXxXx');
var items = form.getItems();

var dateCol = 1
var myID = sheet.getRange(range1, dateCol).getValue();
var dataCol1 = sheet.getRange(range1, dateCol).getValue();

Logger.log(dataCol1)
```

The problem is that after I run the code and use `Logger.log()` to check what value is captured by `getValues()`, nothing appears.
If the content is typed directly into the cell, I am able to return it through `Logger.log()`. But if the cell is contained in the `IMPORTRANGE` range, it doesn't appear in `Logger.log()`.

What should I do to get this to work, so the value of the cell would be returned?

Comment: In order for us to understand the value of  `var range1 = ss.getRange('A1').getDataRegion().getLastRow();` then we have to see the spreadsheet.

Comment: As @Cooper said, we need to see the spreadsheet to better understand the problem. However, I don't understand what you are doing with range1, `getRange('A1')` will get the first cell, `getDataRegion()` will return the same cell (if it's not empty) and lastly, `getLastRow()` will return 1 (because you're still on the first cell). When you get `myID` and you put `...getRange(range1, dateCol).getValue()` it is the same as if you had written `ss.getRange('A1').getValue()`, because range1 abd dateCol are both 1 here. Lastly, you're not using `data` for anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Requirement:

Get value of cell using `IMPORTRANGE` formula.

---

#### Solution:

Instead of using `getValues()`, use `getDisplayValues()`. This returns the displayed value of the cells in a 2d array.

Your line of code would look something like this:

```
var data = ss.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
```

---

#### Reference:

- [`getDisplayValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDisplayValues())

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK formulas are calculated by the Google Sheets UI. Considering this I don't recommend to read spreadsheet formula results when the spreadsheet isn't opened by a user.

One workaround is that the IMPORTRANGE results be saved as values when the spreadsheet is opened by a user at some point on your workflow.

Another, and maybe more reliable, is to use Google Apps Script to do the import job instead on relying on IMPORTRANGE.

Related

- [Spreadsheet function (=importrange()) not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20461439/1595451)
- [Is it possible to do ImportRange in Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11143684/1595451)