# Equivalent of "=Query(ImportRange(" in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

For example in the new google sheet I have these formulas :

`=Query(ImportRange("ehd54...dfdfg", "'Sheet1'!A:C"),"Select * Where Col1 = 'COM' limit 5" ,1)")`

`=Query(ImportRange("ehd54...dfdfg", "'Sheet1'!A:C"),"Select * Where Col2 contains 'IS_A_NAME' limit 5")`

Notes:

- I don't want to use set.Formula(Query(ImportRange(...
- I have seen that I can do the equivalent of importrange here: [Is it possible to do ImportRange in Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143684/is-it-possible-to-do-importrange-in-google-apps-script) but I am blocked for Query.
- my importrange sheets have about 30,000 rows and less than 5 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've "imported" the data, use the [2D Array Library](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/2d-arrays-library) to filter it, then write the results to your sheet.

Comment: Many thanks Mogsdad. ;) I have tested your solution. It seems to work great. ;) But I am blocked on a bug. I have added an example code in the post above because I have difficulties pasting the array in my sheet. Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: I have another request. "ArrayLib.filterByText" is working great if I have `Select * Where Col2 contains 'IS_A_NAME'` but how do I add a limit in order to keep only 5 results ? I have tried `"sh_choix.getRange(37, 1, 5, result[0].length).setValues(result);"` but that doesn't work if I have less than 5 results -for instance 4- ("Incorrect range height, was 4 but should be 5)" ! Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: `sh_choix.getRange(37, 1, result.length, result[0].length).setValues(result);`

Comment: Thanks Magstad. I indeed use your previous comments above about my error with the capital S letter. ;) But my new problem is that I would like to limit the results to 5 maximum even if I have more results than 5.  Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: BTW, I've just found that in the library there is a static version number 23 which adds "ArrayLib.filterByValue". Example: you are looking exactly for = "COM" and it finds exactly "COM" not "ACOM" or "COMMY" (which is what "ArrayLib.filterByText" does).

Comment: For the limit option, I think I have a workaround which is not really great (because it uses google server running time for nothing) but it should do the work. In Sheet1 in A1:C5 I add formulas : A1= Sheet2!A1  ...etc... C5= Sheet2!C5. And I copy/paste the setValues in sheet2. Like that I don't care if there are more than 5 results in sheet2 as I have only 5 results in Sheet1. What do you think ?

Comment: PS: I realize I have forgotten to explain why I would like to use Google Apps Script instead of google formulas is that I have 6 "=Query(ImportRange" running at the same time in a (new) google sheet. Even if the sheet once exported as an xlsx file weight less then 0.5MB, these 6 queries takes in Firefox about 1500MB of RAM in total on my PC (and it has some difficulties to open it). So I can't open the google sheet with a tablet or a smaller PC.

Comment: How to limit number of results? `results=results.slice(0,5)` would do the trick. If you need more, please ask another new question.