# JS Filter an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to filter an array of arrays.

I've searched for an answer on S.O. but all questions I've come accross don't match mine (array of objects or a simple array not nested or not the same format, etc ...)

[image]

Once the values are stored in an array they look like this:

```
[[Paris, One ONE, Boss, Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2017, ], [Paris, Two TWO, Temp, Sat Jul 01 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2017, ], [Paris, Three THREE, Employee, Sat Sep 01 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2018, ], [Paris, Four FOUR, Intern, Thu Nov 01 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2018, ], [Paris, Five FIVE, N.A., Sat Dec 01 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2018, ], [Paris, Six SIX, Director, Tue Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2019, ], [Paris, Seven SEVEN, Director, Fri Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2016, Sun Jul 01 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2018], [Paris, Eight EIGHT, Director, Fri Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2016, Sun Oct 01 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2017], [Paris, Nine NINE, N.A., Thu Nov 01 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2018, Sat Dec 01 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2018], [London, Ten TEN, Employee, Fri Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2016, Mon Oct 01 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2018], [London, Eleven ELEVEN, Intern, Mon Feb 01 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2016, Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2018], [London, Twelve TWELVE, Employee, Sun May 01 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2016, Sun Oct 01 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2017]]
```

I would like to be able to filter this array of arrays and keep the data linked to one community only, Paris for instance.

How would I do that?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: When you say `keep the data linked to one community only` you mean you  want to filter so the result has only the `Paris` rows?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear explanation, yes exactly!

Comment: Please share the code you already have so far and we will help you with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering a two dimensional array in apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51004121/filtering-a-two-dimensional-array-in-apps-script)

Answer (score 6):

you can use Array.filter, somthing like this:

```js
const data = [
['Paris', 'One ONE', 'Boss', 'Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2017' ],
['Paris', 'Two TWO', 'Temp', 'Sat Jul 01 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2017' ],
['London', 'Three THREE', 'Employee, Sat Sep 01 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2018' ]];

const result = data.filter(function(item) { return item[0]==='Paris'});
// const result = data.filter(item => item[0]==='Paris'); // ES6
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Google Apps Script doesn't support arrow functions

Comment: @Rubén, OK, see my edit
I leave the arrow function in a comment just for general use out of Google Apps, Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming all of the elements in your arrays are `Strings`, you just check that each array in your array of arrays contains the element `Paris`.

```js
const yourArray = [
  ['Paris', 'one One', 'whatever else'],
  ['Paris', 'one One', 'whatever else'],
  ['Paris', 'one One', 'whatever else'],
  ['Paris', 'one One', 'whatever else'],
  ['London', 'one One', 'whatever else'],
]

const onlyParis = yourArray.filter(function(array) {
  return array.includes('Paris')
})

console.log(onlyParis)
```

Comment: Google Apps Script doesn't support arrow functions

Comment: @Rubén interesting.  Replaced the arrow function.

Answer (score 1):

I have converted your array to a JavaScript array. And the filter will be done like this:

```js
var myArray = [['Paris', 'One ONE', 'Boss', 'Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2017'],['Paris', 'Two TWO', 'Temp', 'Sat Jul 01 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2017'],['Paris', 'Three THREE', 'Employee', 'Sat Sep 01 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2018'],['Paris', 'Four FOUR', 'Intern', 'Thu Nov 01 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2018'],['Paris', 'Five FIVE', 'N.A.', 'Sat Dec 01 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2018'],['Paris', 'Six SIX', 'Director', 'Tue Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2019'],['Paris', 'Seven SEVEN', 'Director', 'Fri Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2016', 'Sun Jul 01 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2018'],['Paris', 'Eight EIGHT', 'Director', 'Fri Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2016', 'Sun Oct 01 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2017'],['Paris', 'Nine NINE', 'N.A.', 'Thu Nov 01 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2018', 'Sat Dec 01 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2018'],['London', 'Ten TEN', 'Employee', 'Fri Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2016', 'Mon Oct 01 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2018'],['London', 'Eleven ELEVEN', 'Intern', 'Mon Feb 01 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2016', 'Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2018'],['London', 'Twelve TWELVE', 'Employee', 'Sun May 01 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2016', 'Sun Oct 01 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2017']]

var filteredArray = myArray.filter(function (item){
 return item[0] == 'Paris'
})

console.log(filteredArray)
```

Comment: Google Apps Script doesn't support arrow functions

Comment: I have removed the arrow function.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe you would like to take a look to [Filtering a two dimensional array in apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51004121/1595451)

Comment: Sure. The solution for you is a bit different because I thought you wanted to filter based on the first element which is the city.

Answer (score 0):

This function filters the elements of `lst` which are lists. It compares each list's first element (which is the city name in your example) and returns true if and only if it is equal to 'Paris'.

This makes the implicit assumption that the structure of `innerLst` does not change. If the city name is moved to a different index, then larz's solution accounts for that.

```
lst.filter(innerLst => innerLst[0] === 'Paris')
```

Comment: Google Apps Script doesn't support arrow functions

Comment: @Rubén thanks for the heads up, I didn't read the question fully it seems.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const country = [
  ["Paris", "One ONE, Boss, Wed Mar 01 00: 00: 00 GMT + 01: 00 2017", ],
  ["Paris", "Two TWO, Temp, Sat Jul 01 00: 00: 00 GMT + 02: 00 2017", ],
  ["Paris", "Three THREE, Employee, Sat Sep 01 00: 00: 00 GMT + 02: 00 2018", ],
  ["Paris", "Four FOUR, Intern, Thu Nov 01 00: 00: 00 GMT + 01: 00 2018", ],
  ["Paris", "Five FIVE, N.A., Sat Dec 01 00: 00: 00 GMT + 01: 00 2018", ],
  ["Paris, Seven SEVEN, Director, Fri Jan 01 00: 00: 00 GMT + 01: 00 2016, Sun Jul 01 00: 00: 00 GMT + 02: 00 2018"],
  ["London", "Twelve TWELVE, Employee, Sun May 01 00: 00: 00 GMT + 02: 00 2016", "Sun Oct 01 00: 00: 00 GMT + 02: 00 2017"]
]

const res = country.filter(([ville, b, c]) => ville === "Paris")


console.log(res)
```

Comment: Why all the extra levels of arrays? Why not just call filter on the original array>

Comment: cause i just copy paste his input

Comment: Google Apps Script doesn't support arrow functions