# Is there a working version of ImportRange as a script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a working script for importrange (google sheets)? I have done a ton of research and tried scripting one myself and google app scripts just seem to not take the following function:

```
SpreadsheetApp.openById( key )
```

According to my research *openById* is no longer supported and this function has been altered.

Please let me know what I can do to improve on this script and see if there's anything I'm missing.

**(EDIT)**
I want to import a sheet named "Data", from my *Service Area Test Spreadshee*t to a sheet called "Import Here" from my *Test Development Spreadsheet*.

```
function ExportRange() {
  var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById(DESTINATION SPREADSHEET ID HERE);
  var destinationSheet = destination.getActiveSheet();      
  var destinationCell = destinationSheet.getRange(SET DESTINATION CELL EXAMPLE:"A1");
  var cellData = '=IMPORTRANGE(origin spreadsheet_key, range_string)';
  destinationCell.setValue(cellData);
}
```

Based on the script above, this is how I inserted everything.

```
function ExportRange() {
  var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID from "Import Here" here);
  var destinationSheet = destination.getActiveSheet();      
  var destinationCell = destinationSheet.getRange("A1"); //Dropping "Data" starting from "A1"
  var cellData = '=IMPORTRANGE(ID from "Data" here, "A1:L1")'; // My range string is "A1:L1"
  destinationCell.setValue(cellData);
}
```

Comment: "According to my research openById is no longer supported" Do you have a source for this?

Comment: Hello @Tedinoz,nice to hear from you again. Here is the link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143684/is-it-possible-to-do-importrange-in-google-apps-script

As I was reading into this thread, it lead me to more discussions and people having suggestions to just use an API, however, seeing this is part of a work project, I don't have that kind of back up at work to get an API. So trying to learn to script it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

openByID function is supported and working as normal [1]. Be aware that the ID is the code in the spreadsheet's URL and it's something like this "1F45t1mfewf0Zum0AHV43gIl3KEXTvsb3hnNkh29bdsQfS".

I tested your code and worked without problem. Make sure you're passing the SpreadSheet ID and Range parameters as strings (enclosed in "") in the openById and getRange functions, probably this is causing the problem.

Also the formula won't work if you don't previously set the spreadsheetID and range in the cellData string.

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String)

Comment: Duarte Thank you for taking a look into this. I must not be understanding this, please take a look at my editted script posted above for your analysis of my discrepancies. In the post I have to separate google sheets **Test Development** and **Service Area Test**.
<br/>

Comment: Also, I'm adding the script to my "Test Development" Spreadsheet in case you need to know that piece of info.

Comment: The ID is not the same as the URL. I edited my answer to give you an example.

Comment: hmmm I do have only the IDs?? Please see the links below to both of my sheets. This is a company owned level account and you'll have to ask for permission to both sheets. I'm actively on right now so if you ask I can give you permission immediately.

**Test Development**: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gkWCU0fHotORi-urOfuHjGGiqrnYcdtZQ9bZhm7XLIk/edit#gid=705588429           **Service Area Test**: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1je3bHaYCMwa0O9GhnzXr0KbRkdAYSpjHgjMySQDL_nM/edit#gid=0

Comment: Finally getting back to this. Hey @Andre Duarte, after reading your response I noticed (really late) you mentioned, "_Also the formula won't work if you don't previously set the spreadsheetID and range in the cellData string_.". I was not aware I still needed to add a formula for I assumed the point of my script was to importrange the data I needed without it for the ImportRange formula has been quite tempermental and a bit buggy. Is this necessary in order for my script to work?

Comment: Just wanted to thank you and I figured out my problem. My dumb ass did not run the script properly to give permissions for the script to run. Therefore, it worked! So...yea, my bad! I want to thank you for your responses and your help! Have a great day, appreciate the help, cheers!